# communicating with the process while executing a shell command with java

Tags: java, linux, shell, ubuntu, darknet

I'm going to execute a shell command from java and i need to pass arguments to the output stream while executing the command..

following is the shell command

```
./darknet detect cfg/yolo-voc.2.0.cfg backup/yolo-voc_20000.weights
```

when executing this command it is yielding for the path of the image file in the terminal i can provide the path of the image as follows

```
Loading weights from backup/yolo-voc_21000.weights...Done!
Enter Image Path:
```

when executing from the terminal i can provide the path there.

I managed to execute this command withing the java process and also i can get an output when i provide an image uri with the command. here is the code

```
     public static void execCommand(String command) {
    try {

        Process proc = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command);
        // Read the output
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(proc.getInputStream()));

        String line = "";
         //reader.readLine();
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            System.out.print(line + "\n");
            s.add(line);
        }
//            proc.waitFor();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println("exception thrown: " + e.getMessage());
    } 
}
```

but what I want is provide the image path at the runtime not beginning of the execution of the command..
tried with writing to the output stream as below still no luck

```
public static void execCommand(String command) {
    try {
        Process proc = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command);
        // Read the output
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(proc.getInputStream()));

        String line = "";
                    BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(proc.getOutputStream()));
             writer.append("data/test2.jpg");
          writer.newLine();
         //reader.readLine();
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            System.out.print(line + "\n");
            s.add(line);
        }
//            proc.waitFor();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println("exception thrown: " + e.getMessage());
    } 
}
```

Comment: Just a thought -- does the program you are invoking actually read its input from stdin? Does it work as you want if you pipe the filename into it using shell redirection from the command line? If it doesn't, then most likely what you're doing in Java won't work either. It's not all that uncommon for command-line utilities to use low-level methods to read keyboard data.

Comment: yes when i invoke `./darknet detect cfg/yolo-voc.2.0.cfg backup/yolo-voc_20000.weights data/test2.jpg`  via jvm it returns the output successfully.. but i want to give the path later. because darknet loads the weight file first. then i can give images to darknet to process. if i give the file name also it will execute only for that particular jpg and terminates. but i want to process the procedure to more images once loaded the weight file

Comment: Sorry, I didn't express myself very well. I meant, what happens if you do `echo /path/to/something | ./darknet detect...` ? If it still prompts for a filename, then it isn't getting input from stdin, and you won't be able to make it work in Java by simulating stdin.

Comment: `echo data/test2.jpg | ./darknet detect cfg/yolo-voc.2.0.cfg backup/yolo-voc_20000.weights ` works perfectly.. it doesn't yeild for another input it works just like this `./darknet detect cfg/yolo-voc.2.0.cfg backup/yolo-voc_20000.weights data/test2.jpg `

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to call `writer.flush()` in order to actually output something to the underlining `InputStream`

Therefore your code should look like:

```
public static void execCommand(String command) {
    try {
        Process proc = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command);

        // Read the output
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new 
            InputStreamReader(proc.getInputStream()));

        String line = "";
        BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(proc.getOutputStream()));
        writer.append("data/test2.jpg");
        writer.newLine();
        // **** add flush here ****
        writer.flush();
        // and remember to close your resource too
        writer.close();
        //reader.readLine();
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            System.out.print(line + "\n");
            s.add(line);
        }
        // ***** close your reader also ****
        reader.close();
        //            proc.waitFor();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println("exception thrown: " + e.getMessage());
    } 
}
```